# How to set android permissions in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-permissions, cordova-3

I've tried to add following lines in the end of "project_root"/www/config.xml (got it from plugin.xml of one of previously installed plugins):

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

But as expected this doesn't work.
I need it for InAppBrowser plugin to load online pages (I don't want to edit it's plugin.xml, because plugin can be updated or reinstalled -> changes will be wiped).

Comment: What permission you want to set. INTERNET?

Comment: I have to do the same thing. Did you found how to add permissions to your app?

Comment: @mimo As power_scriptor (if I'm not mixing him up with another user) suggested in his deleted answer, I set permission in manifest file directly which is located somewhere in project folder (don't remember where). But this manifest file is being reset sometimes, so it's not very reliable method. However I don't know better solution.

Comment: Strange - this looks perfectly fine to me. Can you tell me the steps you follow to, e.g. add the plugin, and then what follows? As a test, you could set up a dummy plugin which has _just_ the `plugin.xml` file - and _just_ this tag (still in a well formed XML document). It won't break cordova - cordova only reads `plugin.xml` to insert relevant files/text in places.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add the android namespace to the `<widget>`: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

2) Add this to your `platform@name=android`:

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

3) Done (of couse, apply the desired permissions)

Your AndroidManifest.xml file will have the desired permissions (even if you delete the platforms folder):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Notice: I'm using Cordova 8 (I guess `<config-file>` is available since 7)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you are editing the wrong file. When you create a new cordova project using the CLI it places a config file for you here "project_root/config.xml". Check to see if you have a config file in that location. If so then make your changes in that file and it should work.